# preventDefault onSubmit no funciona javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, form-submit

Al entregar el formulario necesito que la pagina no se actualice y así ejecute el codigo de inicio de sesion mediante el fetch, hasta donde tenia entendido preventDefault() cumple esta función... pero simplemente no lo hace. Estoy haciendo algo mal?

codigo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Janfa-Login</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Login.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-form">
        <form class="login" id="login">
            <h2>Log in</h2>
            <label>Documento de identidad</label>
            <label id="error">Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos</label>
            <input type="text" id="cedula" placeholder="Documento de identidad">
            <label>Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
            <input type="submit" name="">

            <a href="#">Olvidé mi contraseña</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
</html>
```

codigo javascript:
EDIT:

```
window.onload= () => {
const loginForm= document.getElementById('login')
loginForm.onSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    const cedula = document.getElementById('cedula').value
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value

    fetch('https://janfa.gharsnull.now.sh/api/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({cedula, password})
    })
}

}
```

Comment: Despues de `preventDefault()` intenta con `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @Angel acabo de hacerlo y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Es un error de syntax , solo debes cambiar `loginForm.onSubmit` por `loginForm.onsubmit` el error esta en la **S** mayúscula. Saludos

Comment: @Daniel Oh dios, muchas gracias. Nunca me hubiera imaginado que eso generaba error ya que ambos metodos los recibe el navegador

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es un *typo* en el nombre del método `onSubmit`. El nombre correcto es `onsubmit`. Aquí puedes revisar su documentación:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit

Aquí te dejo una prueba que hice modificando tu código para que el JS imprimiera los valores de cedula y password en la consola, para verificar que el `preventDefault` funciona con el cambio de nombre del método a `onsubmit`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Janfa-Login</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-form">
        <form class="login" id="login">
            <h2>Log in</h2>
            <label>Documento de identidad</label>
            <label id="error">Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos</label>
            <input type="text" id="cedula" placeholder="Documento de identidad">
            <label>Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
            <input type="submit" name="">

            <a href="#">Olvidé mi contraseña</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
window.onload = () => {
  const login = document.getElementById('login');

  login.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const cedula = document.getElementById('cedula').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    console.log(cedula, password);
  }

};
```

Comment: por convencion.... los elementos HTML se le antecede un $, ejemplo `const $login =...`

Comment: En lo personal, prefiero utilizar esa convención cuando declaro una variable que almacenará un objecto jQuery. Por ejemplo `const $login = $('#login');`